# On mouse over should appear ADD button

Tags: html, css, effects

if someone could help me with this, would be great! I have some images on my webpage, and I want to make a small effect, when I'm moving the mouse over the image, should appear ADD button, in the center of the image, and around the button to be a background-color with opacity effect.
I have this HTML code:

```
<span class="img1" style="opacity: 1;"><img class="prodimg" src="img/naturale_pi_5_large.jpg" alt="Lily Pink Bag"></span>
<span class="img2" style="opacity: 0; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="buttoncont">
        <a href="#">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</span>
```

and also this CSS:

```
.buttoncont{
        display:block;
        width:92px;
        margin:0;
        background:#c33a56;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

#content .productlist .product .foot .buttoncont {
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.buttoncont a,
.buttoncont input {
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:90%;

    background:url('img.jpg');

    border:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.buttoncont input:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.miniproductlist .imagecontainer img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline;
    max-width:100%;
    outline:#ffffff 1px solid;
}

.miniproductlist .img2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:81px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are wrapping everything in a container than you can simply accomplish this with CSS ONLY

```
.container button {
   display: none;
}

.container:hover button {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Now what we are doing here is we are hiding the button, and on hovering the container div, we are showing it, alternatively you can use `visibility: hidden;` but that will take up space where `display: none;` wont

Comment: can you explain a little bit more, how do I implement this in my code?

Comment: just wrap the whole thing in a container div and assign `.container` class to it, change the `button` if you are using input submit